# procmail rule to write to two folders

Tags: procmail

I have a procmail rule that looks for email sent to a specific address and saves it to a folder. The rule looks like this and works just fine.

```
:0:
* ^TOarchive@extraspecialbitter.com
/home/pablo/mail/archive
```

I'd like it to write to a second folder as well, but so far everything I've tried hasn't worked. A second rule for the same "TO" address is ignored, as is a second folder following the first, i.e.:

```
:0:
* ^TOarchive@extraspecialbitter.com
/home/pablo/mail/archive
/home/pablo/mail/new
```

I've also tried putting both folders on the same line with delimiters of space, comma and "|", but no joy. The first folder is always used, and the second ignored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work (don't miss `c` to make carbon-copy).

```
:0 c:
* ^TOarchive@extraspecialbitter.com
/home/pablo/mail/archive

:0:
* ^TOarchive@extraspecialbitter.com
/home/pablo/mail/new
```

Or (should work the same):

```
:0
* ^TOarchive@extraspecialbitter.com
{
  :0 c:
  /home/pablo/mail/archive

  :0:
  /home/pablo/mail/new
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Both examples are based on `procmailex` manual page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest, clearest and most maintainable:

:0 c:

- ^TOarchive@extraspecialbitter.com
  /home/pablo/mail/archive
  :0 A:
  /home/pablo/mail/new